# Does Google Maps support the ability to print a marker with a latitude and longitude value pulled from a database?

Tags: postgresql, google-maps, spring-boot

I'm trying to do some research for a Spring project that I'm currently working on and can't find the answer to my question. It involves the ability to save a latitude and longitude value into a PostgreSQL database. The latitude and longitude values are calculated by Google Maps API. I want the Spring application to allow the user to then query the database and print markers on a map based on the latitude and longitude values. Is this possible using Google Maps?

Comment: Where is the map that you want to print the marker - In a web UI? On the tutorial page for the google maps embed api, it shows how to embed a map displaying a coordinate location.

Comment: Apologies I should've clarified the map is on a JSP webpage